# Rails select options dynamically changing based on another select (without ajax)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form where a user selects a school, and then a qualification that the school provides:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.association :education_organization,
                        collection: EducationOrganization.active,
                        include_blank: true
                        %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.association :training_qualification,
                        collection: TrainingQualification.active,
                        include_blank: true
                        %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would like to dynamically scope the qualifications select to only show the qualifications available to the school that is selected.

I don't want to do an ajax call, I'd rather send the whole list at the start and have the client switch the select options offline.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Maybe not the best option, but I would generate a large JSON that pairs schools and qualifications. And then add a simple Event listener that would listen to the school name and populate the qualifications accordingly.

Comment: I would just use jQuery to show/hide the elements you want based on the change in the other select

Comment: I think Rockwell answer might be better than mine as it will keep the previously selected qualification in case the user is going forth and back on the school selection.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, by initially loading all options, then storing the html options and filtering that list by the id of the association as a data attribute.

View:

```
      <%= f.association :education_organization,
                        collection: EducationOrganization.active,
                        include_blank: true
                        %>

      <%= f.association :training_qualification,
                        collection: TrainingQualification.active.map { |tq| [tq.name, tq.id, {data: {org: tq.education_organization.id}}] },
                        include_blank: true
                        %>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  // this is a hack that lets the JS be included anywhere, but only run on pages with the relevant form
  var qualifications_select = $('#user_training_qualification_id');
  if(qualifications_select) { 

    // this stores all select options
    var qualification_options = qualifications_select.html();


    function updateQualSelect(qualifications_select) {
      var selected_org_id = $('#user_education_organization_id :selected').val();
      if(selected_org_id != '') {
        var filtered_options = $(qualification_options).filter(`[data-org=${selected_org_id}]`);
        qualifications_select.html(filtered_options);
      } else {
        qualifications_select.empty();
      }
    }

    // this line filters the select when the other select changes
    $('#user_education_organization_id').change(function() {
      updateQualSelect(qualifications_select);
    });

    // this line filters the select on page load
    updateQualSelect(qualifications_select); 
  }
})
```